# Proving number of partitions of $n$ to $3$ parts at most.

Tags: combinatorics

I have an exercise, to prove that the number of partitions of $n$ to at most $3$ integers is $\frac{(n+3)^2}{12}$ rounded. I tried to prove by induction but I don't know how.

Comment: There are different definitions of "partition." Please give us more information.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of partitions of $n$ into at most $k$ integers is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ into integers no bigger than $k$.  Let's call this number $p(n,k)$.  In general $$p(n,k)=p(n,k-1)+p(n-k,k)$$ starting with $p(0,0)=1$ and $p(n,0)=0$ for $n\not=0$ and zero if $n$ or $k$ are negative.

For given $k$, patterns are going to repeat every $k!$ terms, so we can find and show by induction that $p(m,1)=1$ and $p(2m,2)=p(2m+1,2)=m+1$ for $m \ge 0$ and thus

- $p(6m+0,3)= 3m^2+3m+1 = \frac{((6m+0)+3)^2}{12} + \frac1{4}$
- $p(6m+1,3)= 3m^2+4m+1 = \frac{((6m+1)+3)^2}{12} - \frac1{3}$
- $p(6m+2,3)= 3m^2+5m+2 = \frac{((6m+2)+3)^2}{12} - \frac1{12}$
- $p(6m+3,3)= 3m^2+6m+3 = \frac{((6m+3)+3)^2}{12} + 0$
- $p(6m+4,3)= 3m^2+7m+4 = \frac{((6m+4)+3)^2}{12} - \frac1{12}$
- $p(6m+5,3)= 3m^2+8m+5 = \frac{((6m+5)+3)^2}{12} - \frac1{3}$

Since all the fractions on the right hand side are smaller than $\frac12$, this  leads to the conclusion that you can round and say $$p(n,3)= \left[\frac{(n+3)^2}{12}\right].$$

Comment: I already graduated since :P but I very much appreciate your answer!

Comment: @Michael I was looking at some old unanswered combinatorics questions  - sorry to disturb you

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to sound sarcastic, I actually appreciate the answer. It will be surely helpful for future students that search for these questions. It just made me smile and remember the days I learnt combinatorics, and feel old